Use GPL v3 project for internal use
There is a GPL v3 application that we want to modify and use as internal application in our team/organization without distributing it outside.
Is this allowed by the GPL v3 license?

Are you and all your team employees of the same corporate entity?

Did you read this FAQ: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic
If that FAQ does not answer your question, then you may need to add some more clarification to your Q. as to what your concern is.

@MadHatter yes, all of the team/organization in under same corporate. No one from outside will use it

@Brandin, thanks! This is exactly what I asked.

Firstly, the GPL does not require that you distribute your software; it merely allows it, and sets the conditions should you choose to convey copies to others.
Secondly, making and circulating copies inside a single corporate entity does not count as conveying, and does not trigger GPL obligations.  If some of your team are contractors, though, or employees of some other organisation, then any copies you give to them count as conveyed copies, and you must give them complete corresponding source and the normal rights and obligations the GPL grants.  In particular, you may not attempt to prevent them from distributing it, should they choose to do so.
